# Trying to understand this code for a memory card matching game project

Tags: javascript, function

So this is from free code camp at: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/vanilla-javascript-tutorial-build-a-memory-game-in-30-minutes-e542c4447eae

I am trying to create a similar game on my own, but it has been a WHILE since I've messed with JS.  I am failing to understand what this chunk of code is necessary for...or I guess understand it in general!  The website says that this sets up the matching logic, but if someone could break it down better for me I'd appreciate it!  If you go to the site, the checkForMatch function is manageable for me.  I know that ! makes things boolean and also??? switches them from true to false or the other way around depending on default?  I also can't remember if I have come across a declaration of two variables at once and what that means.

Thank you for your help!  It's been several hours and I think I've hit my mental wall for the day!

Below is the description from the website:

"Now that we have flipping cards, let’s handle the matching logic.
When we click the first card, it needs to wait until another card is flipped. The variables hasFlippedCard and flippedCard will manage the flip state. In case there is no card flipped, hasFlippedCard is set to true and flippedCard is set to the clicked card. Let’s also switch the toggle method to add:"

```
    const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

    let hasFlippedCard = false;
    let firstCard, secondCard;

    function flipCard() {
      this.classList.add('flip');

      if (!hasFlippedCard) {
         hasFlippedCard = true;
         firstCard = this;
         return;
         }

         secondCard = this;
         hasFlippedCard = false;

         checkForMatch();
       }
```

Comment: _"I know that ! makes things boolean"_ - nah, not really. A `!` (in most languages I know) stands for "not". So in this case you can read `if (!hasFlippedCard)` as "if it _not_ hasFlippedCard" ...set it to true, set it as firstCard and return (nothing).

Comment: Thanks for replying!! Is a "not" not the same as a "false" in true/false terms?? Is that not a boolean?

Comment: ! does convert to a boolean, also inverting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your queston on the "!", this means not. You can use it to
check if something is true or false, or if a variable is null, or contains a value. I have added some comments which will explain this below.

```
var test = null;
var theBool = true;
if(!test){ // if test is null or false
 // You will enter this if statement because test is null
}
if(!theBool){ // if theBool is null or false
 // You will not enter this if statement because theBool is 
// true.
}

test = 10;

if(!test){ // if test is null or false
 // You will not enter this if statement now because test is 
 // not null, it has the value of 10.
}

theBool = false;

if(!theBool){ // if theBool is false or null
// You will enter this if statement because theBool is false.
}
```

I have added some comments to the code block you provided also.

```
 // Grabbing everything with a class .memory-card
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard; 
/*
  same as 
  var firstCard;
  var secondCard;
*/

function flipCard() {

  // Adds the css class flip to what you just clicked on.
  this.classList.add('flip');

  // if hasFlipped === false or is null
  if (!hasFlippedCard) {

     // Set has flipped to true
     hasFlippedCard = true;

     // the first card value now = what you have clicked on.
     firstCard = this;

     // Function complete, return and wait for the next click
     return; 
     }

     // First card was set before, currently it is true, so 
     // the if statement was skipped.
     // The second card is now what you clicked on.
     secondCard = this;

    // Setting to false so next time you click, you will be
    // setting the firstCard value again.
     hasFlippedCard = false;

     // Both card values have been set, now check if they are
     // the same as each other.
     checkForMatch();
   }
```

Enjoy JavaScript :)

Comment: Ah! THANK YOU SPANGLE!  I think I had been over-done myself with JS yesterday, this is a great help!!